# How to scrape stock price information from given HTML?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm trying to retrive stock information from yahoo finance. I have figured out how to use re.findall to  get the prices into a list. If the stock symbol/price does not exist, I have found a way to retrive it saying ['No such ticker symbol']. My issue is I need to have the prices and No such ticket symbol found in the same list in order. This is my code so far. Is it possible to have two patterns in findall() so it can put them both into one list??

```
import urllib.request
import re

li = [i.strip().split() for i in open("Portfolio.txt").readlines()]
li[0:26] =[]
li = [x for x in li if x]
li.sort()


def retrieve_page(url):
    my_socket = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    dta = str(my_socket.readall())
    my_socket.close()
    price = re.findall((r'<td class="col-price cell-raw:(.*?)"><span'), dta)
    noprice = re.findall(r'<span class ="no-symbol">(.*?):<strong>', dta)
    print(price)
    print(noprice)

retrieve_page("http://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/AAPL,GOOG,HWP,IBM,MSFT")
```

My output is as follows

```
['107.120003', '552.25', '164.478699', '46.0938']
['No such ticker symbol']
```

Comment: You could probably chain the two expressions together with a `|`.

Comment: Like this?  Because I get an error when I do it                                                           price = re.findall((r'<td class="col-price cell-raw:(.*?)"><span')|(r'<span class="no-symbol">(.*?): <strong>') , dta)

Comment: Is that precisely your actual program, copy-pasted into place? Or is it almost exactly your program, maybe re-typed? Because when I run **that** program, I don't get the output you describe.

Comment: don't use re at all, use beautifulsoup to parse html

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I'd [avoid parsing HTML with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def retrieve_page(url):
    dta = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(dta)
    price = soup.find_all(class_=["col-price", "invalid-symbol"])
    price = [next(x.strings) for x in price]
    # fix up ': '
    price = [x.replace(': ','') for x in price]
    print(price)

retrieve_page("http://finance.yahoo.com/quotes/AAPL,GOOG,HWP,IBM,MSFT")
```

Result:

```
['106.54', '547.45', 'No such ticker symbol', '163.86', '45.86']
```

Comment: OP is using python 3 `next(x.strings) `